# How can I prevent a shell command from being executed?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to prevent someone from typing in and executing a shell command within terminal that might unknowingly cause problems. Let's say for the sake of argument that the command is `rm -rf /`.

My first thought is to write an alias that would catch the command before it runs, but aliases only work on single-word commands. Is there a way to intercept a *specific* command before it runs and echo something like "You cannot run that command" instead of executing?

Comment: Are you talking about a _script_ (i.e. a file that contains a sequence of shell commands to run), or a _command_?

Comment: Sorry, i just meant a "command". Will update

Comment: No, there is no way to prevent a motivated attacker with arbitrary shell access from executing a specific command. You should be using permissions and capabilities, not command blacklisting.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, but the duplicate is being a bit tricky to find -- I wonder if perhaps it's on [unix.se] (where this question would certainly be closer to topic).

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90998/block-particular-command-in-linux-for-specific-user

Comment: I can copy/paste the identical script from another server and execute it.

Comment: @thatotherguy It's less about a motivated attacker and more about preventing someone who is new to programming who might make a substantial mistake.

Comment: @WalterA, you don't even need to do that -- if the restriction is being performed by the shell, just call it in a way that doesn't go through the shell. Even if `somecmd foo` is blocked, `xargs somecmd foo` won't be, much less `python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(['somecmd', 'foo'])`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy When somebody sets the file to 700 (and writes some wrapper code with setuid and check of parameters) `xargs` is blocked.

Comment: @WalterA, ...did you mention any of that work upthread? The response is true enough, but seems like a bit of a non sequitur; the question is tagged "bash", together with the text implying that the OP is looking for a restriction that can be implemented as an (alias-like) shell configuration measure.

Comment: @samcorcos When I was new somebody tried preventing me making a mistake with `alias rm='/bin/rm -i'`. That seemed to work until I changed to a user (root), where the alias was not set. And I made a substantial mistake, expecting confirmation after `rm *`. Try to give new persons minimal rights.

Comment: *nod* -- the best safety net (beyond well-crafted permissions) is a robust snapshot or backup regimen. Doubly so if those snapshots are live for users to read without requesting admin intervention; if you can pick up your files as they existed as of last week by looking in `/snapshots/2018-10-15/home/username`, the threat of deletion gets a lot less scary.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree that an alias can be passed even more easy.

Comment: `alias rm=rm -i` has no effect when `-f` is set, so `rm -f` oder `rm -fi` will never prompt.